# Erase arrays with a variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm creating a macro with a data sheet that has 185 columns.  I need to capture the data in each column for the total number of rows in the data sheet (maybe 800).

I want to capture all of the data so I created variables like this so the number corresponds to the the column number:

```
Public vVar1() as string
Public vVar2() as string
Public vVar3() as string
Public vVar4() as string.....etc.
```

I want to erase the array and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
vCnt = 1
 vTmp = ""

 Do Until vCnt = 186
      DoEvents
      vTmp = "vVar"
      vTmp = vTmp & vCnt

      Erase vTmp

      vCnt = vCnt + 1

Loop
```

However, I'm getting an "Expected Array" error message on the "Erase vTmp" line.  I was trying to do it this way instead of having ERASE vTMP1, ERASE vTmp2.....183 more times.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks......Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe the only way is to make an array of arrays and loop the parent array.  I do not think you can refer to a variable via a string variable.

Comment: @ScottCraner...........Thanks.........I was trying to do it this way for less coding.  Thanks fo the quick reply

Comment: Why not something like `Public vVar as Variant`. And then, in your main code `vVar =Range(Cells(1,1),cells(800,185))` --> a single, 2D array.  Then you can erase the array in a single step.

Comment: 186 variables is less coding ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Erase vTmp
```

`vTmp` is a `Variant/String` here, not an array. Just because the string happens to match the name of a programmatic identifier doesn't make it a magical string that arbitrarily becomes an actual identifier depending on context like it would in PHP - and that's a very, very good thing.

The **real** problem is having 185 arrays to clear in the first place. Whenever you feel the need to number something - *anything* - there's a 99% chance you're in the wrong spot and need to think of a data structure instead. Like Tim said, an array with 185 items that are themselves arrays makes much more sense than having 185 *variables* that go by the names of `vVar1` through `vVar185`.

And then you can `Erase` them, because now you're dealing with arrays, not strings:

```
For i = 0 To 184
    Erase allArrays(i)
Next
```